# Custom Hyperlink Title in MS Access Datasheet

Tags: ms-access, cmd, vba

I'm writing to see if anyone can tell me the fastest way of extracting filenames from a network drive I have offsite. I have some search criteria provided by users with the help of a userform in Access.

I've tried using FSO which in my experience in this situation is the slowest.
I've also tried using CMD with WScript.Shell, which is faster, but I've recorded that it take approximately 7 minutes to perform the check with the macro. Using the Windows search bar in an explorer window provides results in about a minute or less. The parent folders I am searching through have approximately 35,000 folders each containing about 1 to 2 files.

Here is the command I use with CMD with WScript.Shell :

```
    strTemp = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Exec("CMD /C DIR """ & "N:\" & _
                  Me.txtRegion.Value & "\" & Me.txtYear.Value & "\" & _
                  Me.txtDossier.Value & "*.*"" /S /B /A:-D").StdOut.ReadAll
```

The results are then split into an array and processed.

Does anyone have any suggestions for how to improve this code?

Comment: While this would be a good thing to know, it is not particularly well suited to Stack Overflow. SO does -not- seek to expand discussion where many opinions might collide. SO typically deals with finding a solution to code that does not perform as desired. You may get some pushback from SO up to, and including, closing the question.

Comment: @lit, I thought I was asking for help.. the code I posted is not performing as desired. What is the correct format for my question?

Comment: In what way is it not performing as desired? Is it only a question of speed performance?

Comment: Like I said in my post, when I use the Windows Explorer search tool, it takes at the most a minute, but using the macro takes about 7 minutes. That's what I mean by not performing as desired, I wish it would take much less. I've tried the macro on another drive and it takes less than 5 seconds to run, even while using a VPN.